# Lightning Web Component - Create Contact Error: afterRender threw an error in 'c:lWCDemoComponent' [Cannot read property 'objectApiName' of undefined]

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to create a contact on the contact page... Just for learning and understanding Web Components. Below is the code I am getting an error of:

afterRender threw an error in 'c:lWCDemoComponent' [Cannot read property 'objectApiName' of undefined]

Stack Trace: g.set objectApiName()@https://gatan--stagging.lightning.force.com/components/interop/recordEditForm.js:2:4061

This is a walk through of the blog: https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2018/12/introduction-to-lightning-web.html

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Contact" icon-name="standard:contact">

<lightning-record-form object-api-name={objectApiName} record-id={recordId} 
                       fields={fields}></lightning-record-form>

</lightning-card>
</template>


 import { LightningElement , api, track} from 'lwc';

export default class LWBDemoComponent extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
@api objectApiName;
@track fields = ['Name', 'Title', 'Phone', 'Email'];
}



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="LWBDemoComponent">
<apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>True</isExposed>
  <targets>
<target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>lightning__HomePage</target>
```

Comment: Where are you expecting the objectApiName to be initialized from? Did you mean to add it in the meta.xml as a targetConfigs/targetConfig/property for the person putting the component into the page to set?

Comment: Note, too, that the recordId will only get populated when the target is lightning__RecordPage. In all other cases this will remain undefined (unless you make it a targetConfigs/targetConfig/property as well).

Comment: Also note that you don't need "fields" to be tracked unless you are expecting this array to be changed dynamically at some point.

Comment: Is there a better example that i can work from... I understand coding in APEX and Visualforce well but not Web Components.

Comment: If I had a working simple example, I could figure out how to code in Lightning without issue....

Comment: I suggest you use the trailheads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to give a default value to **objectApiName** attribute when you are using the component outside the record context. As property is annonated with @api, it will get automatically changed.

You need to know these points:-

1. If a component is used on a Lightning record page, you can pass the component the API name of the current object. In the component’s JavaScript class, use the @api decorator to create a public **objectApiName** property.
2. When your component is invoked in a record context in Lightning Experience or in the mobile app, the objectApiName is set to the API name of the object associated with the record being viewed, for example: Warehouse__c.
3. The objectApiName is set only when you place or invoke the component in an explicit record context. In all other cases, the objectApiName isn’t set, and your component shouldn’t depend on it.

Reference:- [Make a Component Aware of Its Object Context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_object_context)